# Dynamic Identity based on value of other column

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I am Creating a table such as  student name, class ,roll no

roll no is set as identity,information of student is being saved in on table  such as student name,class,roll no

i want such that

```
Student Name    Class   Roll No
   Snehal         1      1
    Alok          1      2
   Sandeep        1      3
  Swapnil         1      4
   Kunal          1      5
   Amit           1      6
  Nitin           2      1
 Sudhanshu        2      2
  Lokesh          1      7
  Swati           2      3
  Rajesh          1      8
```

i want that when i insert any person name and enter in class 1 then automatically its roll no should be 9 and when i insert any name and put class 2 then roll no should be 4 and if i enter the person name with class 3 then its roll no should start from 1 as it is 3rd class first record and after that i enter the person name and put class 1 then 10 it want to use identity function in this manner please suggest me as soon as possible me in "die hard condition"

Comment: what RDBMS you use? Plese add tag with that.

Comment: after looking at your edit, why do you need to store this value? you can have a unique id per row with a standard ID column, and you can get the roll no per class when you return data. You should perhaps just consider a composite key made up of student ID column and class Id, which will be a unique combination. what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Actually i am designing a application in which i will be displaying customer information to our client then from our client end they will be entering the class of customer according to there information and there can be a multiple class. so my requirement is that i am having two columns class and serial_No_InClass so i want whenever a existing class is added then the identity should be increment by 1 and if a new class is entered the its identity should start from 1 and after that a existing class is entered again then the number should be grater than the last identity number of that record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use SQL Server's [**ROW_NUMBER()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) function to create a partition by the `Class`. This will effectively order the results by the class column and give `RollNo` a sequential value until the class changes.

**SQL Schema Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE StudentClass
    ([Student Name] varchar(9), [Class] int)
;

INSERT INTO StudentClass
    ([Student Name], [Class])
VALUES
    ('Snehal', 1),
    ('Alok', 1),
    ('Sandeep', 1),
    ('Swapnil', 1),
    ('Kunal', 1),
    ('Amit', 1),
    ('Nitin', 2),
    ('Sudhanshu', 2),
    ('Lokesh', 1),
    ('Swati', 2),
    ('Rajesh', 1)
;
```

**SQL SELECT Using `ROW_NUMBER()`:**

```
SELECT  * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY Class ) AS RollNo
FROM    StudentClass
```

**Output:**

```
Student Name    Class   RollNo
===============================
Snehal              1       1
Alok                1       2
Sandeep             1       3
Swapnil             1       4
Kunal               1       5
Amit                1       6
Lokesh              1       7
Rajesh              1       8
Swati               2       1
Nitin               2       2
Sudhanshu           2       3
```